# Как изменить значение переменной в пуле?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
// по нажатию создается пуля и помещается в пул, затем берется из него
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
        Bullet item = bulletPool.obtain();
        item.init(item.getX(), item.getY(), player.getsGun().getRotation());
        activeBullets.add(item);
    }


    // обновить пули, если за пределами экрана - вернуть в пул
    for (Bullet bullet : activeBullets) {
        bullet.update(dt);
        if (bullet.outOfScreen) {
            activeBullets.removeValue(bullet, true);
            bulletPool.free(bullet);
        }
    }
```

Насколько я понял, в пул заносится пуля с сохраненным `init(item.getX(), item.getY(), player.getsGun().getRotation());`, то есть пуля в пуле имеет конкретнуб координату X, Y, а так же неизменяемое значение Rotation - каждая пуля из пула будет лететь с таким rotation, с каким была внесена в пул. И теперь вопрос - как менять значения rotation в пуле? Мне нужно, чтобы пуля из пула летела в ту точку, куда повернута башня (а она вращается постоянно).

Update:
Мм, дело в том, что пуля не знает, куда ей лететь. Вот код пули без использования пула

```
public class Bullet extends BasicObject {

private float lifeTime;
private float lifeTimer;

private boolean remove;

public Bullet(float x, float y, float radians) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y+50;
    this.radians = radians;

    float speed = 350;
    dx = MathUtils.cos(radians) * speed;
    dy = MathUtils.sin(radians) * speed;

    width = height = 2;

    rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    lifeTimer = 0;
    lifeTime = 2;
}

public boolean shouldRemove() {
    return remove;
}

public void update(float dt) {

    x += dx * dt;
    y += dy * dt;
    rectangle.x = x;
    rectangle.y = y;

    lifeTimer += dt;
    if (lifeTimer > lifeTime) {
        remove = true;
    }

}

public void draw(ShapeRenderer sr) {

    sr.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    sr.circle(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width / 2);
    sr.end();

    }

}
```

А вот класс `Player`:

```
public class Player extends BasicObject {

private ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
private final int MAX_BULLETS = 20;

private Texture tTower;
private Texture tGun;
private Sprite sTower;
private Sprite sGun;

private float curAngle;

private Rectangle rGun;

radians = 3.1415f / 2;

public Player(ArrayList<Bullet> bullets) {

    this.bullets = bullets;

    x = MyMainClass.WIDTH / 2;
    y = 0;


    // tower
    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.x = x - 64/2;
    rectangle.y = y;
    rectangle.width = 64;
    rectangle.height = 64;

    rGun = new Rectangle();
    rGun.x = x - 64/2;
    rGun.y = y + 10;
    rGun.width = 64;
    rGun.height = 64;

    tTower = new Texture("TOWER.png");
    sTower = new Sprite(tTower);

    tGun = new Texture("TOWER_GUN.png");
    sGun = new Sprite(tGun);

    sTower.setPosition(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
    sGun.setPosition(rGun.x, rGun.y);
    sGun.setOrigin(sGun.getWidth() / 2, sGun.getHeight() - sGun.getHeight());

}

public void shoot() {
    if (bullets.size() == MAX_BULLETS) return;
    bullets.add(new Bullet(x, y, radians));
}

public float getX(){return x;}
public float getY(){return y;}

public void update(float dt) {

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

            // тут код по нахождению угла поворота башни и ограничении ее движения
            .......
            .......



 // set rotation
    radians = (MathUtils.PI / 180 * sGun.getRotation())+ MathUtils.PI/2;

}

public void draw(SpriteBatch sb) {

        sb.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

        sb.begin();

        sTower.draw(sb);
        sGun.draw(sb);

        sb.end();


    }

}
```

В `PlayState` я пишу `if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
            player.shoot();
        }`
, и в итоге пуля летит туда, куда повернута пушка. И все бы ничего, только пуля постоянно создается заново, а затем удаляется, а таких создающихся объектов хватает и помимо пули, вот и пытаюсь сделать пул

Comment: почему не сделать метод `bullet.setRotation(double angle)` ?

Comment: @Nofate, добавил для примера классы `Bullet`  и `Player` без использования пула

Comment: Не вижу где вы используете названный pool с пулями, у вас при вызове shoot пули создаются через     bullets.add(new Bullet(x, y, radians));

Comment: Там не создаётся новая пуля, а добавляется в activeBullets (смотрите самое начало вопроса). В любом случае, решение проблемы я написал - нужно писать не getRotation(), а расписывать подробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблема в этом: `item.init(item.getX(), item.getY(), player.getsGun().getRotation());` - точнее, в `player.getsGun().getRotation());`. я просто заменил его (и разбил эту строку на отдельные части) на вот это `item.setDx(MathUtils.cos(player.getRadians()) * item.getSpeed());
item.setDy(MathUtils.sin(player.getRadians()) * item.getSpeed());` из класса `Bullet` (короче, вручную указал dx и dy в основном классе), и все заработало нормально - теперь пули летят только туда, куда нужно